# Is visas a plural of a plural?

Tags: plural-forms

Visa, like many other neutral gender Latin words with a singular ending in -um, is the plural form of visum.

Visas is thus the plural form of the plural form, comparable to
mouse - mice - ‘mices’ or
goose - geese - ‘geeses’.
Same goes for quotum - quota - ‘quotas’.
What is your expert opinion on this matter?

Answer (score 4):

Don't assume that a word that has been borrowed from another language will retain its meaning, pronunciation, or grammatical function in English.

The word visa, in English is a singular countable noun, and the plural is "visas"

(The etymology is that visa is short for "charta visa" = document that has been seen. "visa" is the of the nominative feminine **singular** of the perfect passive participle of videō, so not a plural at all, not not a noun either.  Quota comes from a shortening of *quota pars*, and is the nominative feminine singular. Again, not plural, not even a noun)

[You might have a better case with "data", which is a Latin plural noun, but usually treated as singular uncountable in English, although "datum" is occasionally used.  As an observation, in English maths tests for all students at age 16, "data" is treated as singular: "this data". In advanced level tests for students at 18 it treated as plural.  I doubt that many students even notice.]

[Further case, while I'm on the subject: "referenda" is a hypercorrection of the correct "referendums" since there is no Latin plural of the gerund *referendum*. But it is common enough that it can be accepted as an irregular plural.]

Comment: In European passports a ‘visa’ is still a visum, oddly enough. In other cases like quotum, quantum, medium there seems to be no rule as to what the English language does

Comment: @Alex Reysenbach - Do you have photographic evidence of that? I think you might be mistaken.  P.S. Are you talking about German text?

Comment: According to Wiktionary, Danish and Dutch use "visum". But what does it matter? Even if "visa" were a Latin plural, that wouldn't make it an English plural. The etymology is ultimately irrelevant, albeit interesting. As James rightly says, it's an English singular noun.

Comment: There is a Latin word "visum" with a plural "visa" but it means "a vision" It's not the source of the English word Visa. Use of "visum" in Dutch might be a hypercorrection.

Comment: @rjpond - It matters because this is an English site. If the OP is offering a German word as evidence against the answer by James K, then the OP's counter-argument is invalid and this needs to be pointed out.

Comment: Nouns like quantum, museum, medium, quotum and others are ‘borrowed’ from Latin, a language that no longer evolves. Why not use their correct plural forms, or just add an ‘s’ to all of them, as in the case of for example museums? There is no uniformity. Is language ‘a living thing’ and my thinking too rigid, or is the most often made error adopted?

Comment: @Alex Reysenbach - This has nothing to do with your original question which was about "visa". You incorrectly assumed that "visa" was a plural which it is not. How does this relate to words that genuinely end in "-um"?  As for why language is the way it is, I might as well ask why German 'incorrectly' uses "visum".  Language was not invented by  teams of mathematicians and logicians but by ordinary people doing the best they can.

Comment: Please read the answer!  We didn't borrow "quotum"  we borrowed "quota pars"  which is singular and then shortened it (because who has enough time to say "pars"?).  The word "quota" is a singular adjective in Latin.  It is a singular noun in English.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica You are correct.

Comment: There may actually be some uncertainty about the etymology.  The OED specifies that it's a Latin feminine (without mentioning "charta").  Etymonline and Wiktionary have the feminine ("charta") theory.  But Lexico and Merriam-Webster both state that Latin "visa" is a neuter plural. ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visa ; https://www.lexico.com/definition/visa ). Collins regards it as plural in its British English etymology, singular in its AmE etymology (borrowed from Webster's New World Dictionary) ( https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visa ).